# unable to get call from anchor tag using onclick in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

cshtml code

```
<div class="span3">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.GroupNames.Count; i++)
    {
        <ul>                 
            <li>
                @{
                    var item = Model.GroupTypeNames[i];
                    var selected = i == 0 ? " class=\"selected\"" : "";
                }

                <a onclick="getGroupType(@item.Id);" data-option-value="*"@Html.Raw(selected)>@item.TypeName</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

jquery code

```
function getGroupType(id) {
    debugger;
    $.getJSON( "Groups/Get" + id, function (data) {
        $(".span9").html($("#GroupTemplate").removeData());
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            if (value.Id != undefined) {
                $("#GroupTemplate").tmpl(value).appendTo(".span9");
            }
        });

        $('#circle').css("opacity", "0.5");
    });
}
```

Unable to get call here
but when I try to use `onclick="alert('Hello');"` it is working perfectly

what wrong with `onclick="getGroupType(@item.Id);"`

Comment: `$(".span9").html($("#GroupTemplate").removeData());` what this line is doing? also if you could post the error in browser console if there is any?

Comment: Are you getting an errors?  You will need to wrap `@item.Id` in ''

Comment: View the rendered source and check if the `@item.Id` is being output correctly in the onclick attribute.

Comment: no errors thats the most tricky part :(

Comment: forget about other code which is inside function getGroupType(id) as even debugger is not able to hit

Comment: why don't you try with `breakpoints` in the source tab at your script.

Comment: What does the html look like after the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented:

*my function is in ready*

so i think here is a scoping issue, because your `onclick` handler is not in the ready function so your function `getGroupType(@item.Id);` is not available for it, instead you can put it outside in the gloabal scope.

```
getGroupType(id){
  // all the stuff
}

$(function(){
   // all other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would expect you get the error:

> ReferenceError: getGroupType is not defined

Because I suspect that your JavaScript code appears later in the file than your `onclick` attribute.

When using attributes, make sure the function is defined before the attributes... usually in the `<head>`. Having said this, normal practice is to include scripts later and attach the events in the script, rather than using attributes.

Also, make sure your function isn't wrapped inside another function. JavaScript is functionally scoped, and a function wrapped in another function won't be callable from global scope.

This all assumes `id` is actually a number. If the `id` is a string, remember to wrap it in quotes too. GUIDs must be treated like strings in JavaScript...

```
onclick="getGroupType('@item.Id');"
```

Comment: Here is a recreation of the problem I suspect: http://jsfiddle.net/ka6Wn/ - and then working in this one (script in the head) http://jsfiddle.net/B4x53/

Comment: @ashish put it outside of ready in gloabal scope, this is why it is not getting hit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wrap the parameter with Single Quotes.

```
onclick="getGroupType('@item.Id');"
```

Comment: Jai. Do you still think we are not required to wrap it in quotes?

Comment: GUIDs need to be treated like strings - as @CodingDawg said.